# How to set the returnURL manually when using Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this link

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("create poll question", 
                 "CreatePoll", 
                 new { id = Model.DebateID }, 
                 new AjaxOptions
                 {
                   UpdateTargetId = "poll-entry-box",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                   HttpMethod = "GET"
                 })
```

which is pointing at a action with the [Authorize] Attribute. The login works, but the returnURL is empty so it just redirects to the index page.

Is there some way to manually set the returnURL ?

*NOTE*

I am using the method described here http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx because the login page was loading inside my partial.

Comment: Im thinking maybe I can create a session variable that I update on every page and when I hit a login page set the returnURL to that value.. still thinking, not quite answer material yet.

Comment: What does your controller method look like?

Answer (score 0):

One possible option would be setting the [`.OnComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete.aspx) property with a JavaScript function that sets the `returnUrl` query string.

you could implement a function *similar* to this:

```
var setReturnUrl(url) {
    var currentUrl = window.location;
    if(-1 != currentUrl.indexOf('returnUrl')) {
        var x = currentUrl.split('?');
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
            if(-1 != x[i].indexOf('returnUrl')) {
                currentUrl = currentUrl.replace(x[i], 'returnUrl=' + url);
            }
        }
    } else {
        currentUrl = currentUrl + '&returnUrl=' + url;
    }
    window.location = currentUrl;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm also currently looking at getting the referrer off the Request object.. heard it can be unreliable so still experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

What about,

```
     @Ajax.ActionLink("create poll question", 
"CreatePoll", new { id = Model.DebateID, returnUrl = "YOUR_URL" } ...
```

**UPDATE:**

It's been clarified that returnUrl, produces just yet another attribute for . What we need to do instead is fix href parameter.

I propose to create your own version of @Ajax.ActionLink that might handle returnUrl.

```
public static MvcString ActionLink(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string actionName, string returnUrl, object routerValues)
{
  // ...
}
```

Inside this method, you can use TagBuilder class, to produce the  link, matching your need. Take a look on [CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/944ab06b9c54#src/System.Web.Mvc/Ajax/AjaxExtensions.cs) how Ajax.ActionLink is implemented.

Comment: returnURL still ends up empty in the controller

Comment: could you please show, what mark-up does it generates (with returnUrl parameter);

Comment: It creates this link <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#comment-entry-box" href="/Debate/CreateDebateComment/1?returnURL=%2FDebate%2FDetails%2F">comment</a>